# How to fix the design of the Header on dataTable while Draging

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, material-ui, angular-datatables

i'm setting a reorder-able table,
Using { mat-table , MatTableDataSource }
but when i drag a column i want it's place to have a white background color not transparent.
Can this be done?
Exemple Picture link : https://i.stack.imgur.com/LSIdY.jpg

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort class="mat-elevation-z8" cdkDropListGroup *ngIf="Loaded">
   <ng-container [matColumnDef]="column" *ngFor="let column of columnsWithoutSelect; let i = index" >
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header  cdkDropList
                        cdkDropListLockAxis="x"
                        cdkDropListOrientation="horizontal"
                        (cdkDropListDropped)="dropListDropped($event, i)"
                        cdkDrag
                        (cdkDragStarted)="dragStarted($event, i)"
                        [cdkDragData]="{name: column, columIndex: i}"> {{headsColumns[column]}} </th>

                        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" [ngClass]="stateRow ? 'td-min-1': 'td-min-2'"  > {{element[column]}} </td>
                    </ng-container>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply add custom styles to your drag list.
`<th mat-header-cell class="drop-list`

css

```css
.drop-list{
  width: 100%;
  border: solid 1px #ccc;
  min-height: 60px;
  display: block;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 4px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

> This are just examples styles you have to adjust them to fit your needs.

For further examples see [here](https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview)

Also `cdkDropList` and `cdkDrag` should not be on the same element.

Set `cdkDropList` to your `<th>` and `cdkDrag` to you `<td>`